# How to set XSSFSheet orientation to Landscape .NET NPOI

Tags: .net, orientation, landscape, npoi

How do I set the Print Orientation of an XSSFSheet to Landscape in .NET?

I can only find Java related solutions for this, and this doesn't work in .NET:

```
printSetup.setLandscape(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sheet.PrintSetup.Landscape = True
```